# Как правильно сохранять формы PHP, JS, WYSIWYG?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток!

Есть форма с несколькими полями,одно из которых - текст статьи. Так как это статья - то там должен быть и текст и картинки.

Для ввода данных использую [bootstrap wysihtml](http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/). Вставленные картинки сохраняются в виде

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD..
```

потом передаю с помощью jquery

```
var article_text = $('#editor').html();
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/article/save",
        data: {article_text:article_text},
```

Текст статьи сохраняю в отдельной таблице, но даже когда пытаюсь вывести текст статьи - происходит исключение из-за длинной строки.
Решение этой проблемы я вижу две:

1. Сжимать строку в js. А потом при отображении распаковывать
2. Парсить передаваемую строку на наличие картинок, сохранять картинку на отдельный файл, а хранить в БД только ссылку на картинку.

Может Вы подскажете как быть (по-любому кто-то уже сталкивался с этим).

Comment: С подобным не сталкивался, так как делал сразу, и иначе. Но я предполагаю, что нужно смотреть в сторону второго варианта.

Comment: а как делал?

Comment: > Текст статьи сохраняю в отдельной таблице, но даже когда пытаюсь вывести текст статьи - происходит исключение из-за длинной строки. Решение этой проблемы я вижу две

Выяснить, что это за исключение, и почему БД не поддерживает длинные тексты как решение даже не рассматривается?